# Setting General Messages Using Flash Message

Tags: php

I have a simple register form, my form validates but will not show error messages or validation messages

This is my form function

```
function validate_new_user()
{
    $errors = [];

    if (isset($_POST['register'])) {

        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $name = str_replace(" ", "", $_POST['username']);
        $password = $_POST['password'];

        if (empty($email)) {
            $errors[] = "Email Address is required";
        }
        if (empty($name)) {
            $errors[] = "Username is required";
        }
        if (strlen($password) < 5) {
            $errors[] = "Password must be at least 6 characters long";
        }
        if (!empty($errors)) {
            set_message($errors[0], WARNING);
        } else if (create_new_user($email, $name, $password)) {

            set_message('Please check your email for user Information.', SUCCESS);
            redirect_to_url("/user/login");

        }
    }
 }
```

I call my validation function in my form page

```
<?php validate_new_user(); ?>
```

so if there is an error it should set message but don't.

now if it successfully it redirects to login and sets a flash message also and I call it with

```
<?php display_message(); ?>
```

That don't display a message either

Flash message code

```
define('SUCCESS', 'success');
define('INFO', 'info');
define('WARNING', 'warning');


function set_message($message, $type = 'success')
{
    if (!empty($_SESSION['flash_notifications'])) {
        $_SESSION['flash_notifications'] = [];
    }
    $_SESSION['flash_notifications'][] =
        $message = [
            '<div class="alert . $type .">$message</div>'
        ];
}


function display_message()
{
    if (isset($_SESSION['flash_notifications'])){
        return $_SESSION['flash_notifications'];
    }
}
```

my goal is to use one set message for all notifications with styles but I cannot get none of the messages to display

Comment: I see two errors right off the bat: 1) if it displays anything, it will be `'$message'`, because the variables are not being interpreted in single quotes. 2) `display_message()` returns a value, but never prints it. Actually, I think it’s better to do `display_message()` as you have it; you just need to use the short print tag to display it: `<?= display_message() ?>`

Comment: woops, thats an array. You need to `join()` or `implode()` it.

Comment: @TimMorton I was trying not to have a bunch of spaghetti code, I was trying to have the errors and messages in one swoop

Comment: I don’t see any spaghetti code here, just a few honest mistakes. I’ll type up an answer and hopefully make it broad enough to be of value to others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’ll assume you’re calling `session_start()` at the beginning of the script.

Your usage of functions makes the problem much easier to diagnose! Sometimes, though, it helps to have a different set of eyes look at it.

Your function `set_message()` has a couple of errors:

1. The initialization of  `$_SESSION['flash_notifications']` should occur if it is *empty*, but instead you are initializing if it is *not* empty. Hence nothing can be added
2. Malformed assignment. When you are building the message array to save in `$_SESSION`, there is no need to reassign `$message`. Also, usage of single quotes does not interpret variables within the quotes, so the html snippet is not what you expect.

Corrected function:

```
function set_message($message, $type = 'success')
{
    if (empty($_SESSION['flash_notifications'])) {
        $_SESSION['flash_notifications'] = [];
    }
    $_SESSION['flash_notifications'][] = '<div class="alert '. $type .'">'.$message.'</div>';
}
```

Note, it might be more understandable to write it this way:

```
    $_SESSION['flash_notifications'][] = <<<FLASH

<div class="alert $type'">$message</div>
FLASH;
```

Your function `display_message()` is almost correct as is, except you’re returning an array, not a string. If you’re going to print it, it must be converted into a string:

```
function display_message()
{
    if (isset($_SESSION['flash_notifications'])){
        return join('',$_SESSION['flash_notifications']);
    }
}
```

Then when you call it in your html, use the short print tag instead of the regular `<?php` tag:

```
<!— somewhere in your view (html output) —>

<?= display_message() ?>

<!— continue html —>
```